# INV A*b can be slower and less accurate tha A/b Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

I'm working on the *collision detection* of two boxes and transfer their *velocities* with their *masses* affect in order to make scenario of after *collision* effects. I'm using currently `INV()` for inverse of matrix but *Matlab* gives a warning that this might slow, and use A/b instead of `INV A*b` but it doesn't show correct results, What suggestions about my scenario as i'm only interested in after *collision* affect of second box whose have initially zero *velocity*.

**My Code:**

```
for time=0:dt:tf
    i=i+1;
    %check for collision
    if abs(xB2-xB1)<=3 && collision_count==0
        collision_count=collision_count+1;
        VB_after_collision=inv(-[mB1 mB2;1 -1])*(0.9*(VB2-VB1));
        VB2=VB_after_collision(1);

    else


            if abs(VB2)>0.005*mB2*9.81*dt %necessary condition for the box to keep moving against fricition
                VB2=VB2-0.005*mB2*9.81*dt*sign(VB2);
            else
                VB2=0;
            end
    end
        xB1=xB1+VB1*dt;
        xB2=xB2+VB2*dt;

boxes(xB1,xB2);

end
```

I'm currently using `VB_after_collision(1)` but I want only this in my scenario.

Comment: Are you sure MATLAB didn't suggest `A \ b`?  The direction of the slash matters.

Comment: Yeah, I also used this but it is also giving inaccurate results.

Comment: Is the matrix non square?

Comment: No, it is squared Matrix. let me update my code so that u can understand better.